# How do GPUs (Geforce 9800) implement bitwise integer operations?

Tags: cuda, gpu, bitwise-operators

CUDA gives the programmer the possibility to write something like `a & b | ~ c` (`a`, `b`, `c` being `unsigned int`s).

What does the GPU do internally? Does it somehow "emulate" bitwise operations on integers or are they similarily efficient like on a traditional CPU?

Comment: Please provide a reference to what you have read, otherwise it's just hearsay, and difficult to comment on. "i've read that many stack overflow users don't rtfm".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [CUDA Programming Guide v2.3](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/2_3/toolkit/docs/NVIDIA_CUDA_Programming_Guide_2.3.pdf) (Section 5.1.1.1) the bitwise operations run at full speed (8 operations per clock cycle).

> **Integer Arithmetic**
>
> Throughput of integer add is 8
>   operations per clock cycle.
>
> Throughput of 32-bit integer
>   multiplication is 2 operations per
>   clock cycle, but mul24 provide 24-bit
>   integer multiplication with a
>   troughput of 8 operations per clock
>   cycle. On future architectures
>   however, mul24 will be slower than
>   32-bit integer multiplication, so we
>   recommend to provide two kernels, one
>   using mul24 and the other using
>   generic 32-bit integer multiplication,
>   to be called appropriately by the
>   application.
>
> Integer division and modulo operation
>   are particularly costly and should be
>   avoided if possible or replaced with
>   bitwise operations whenever possible:
>   If n is a power of 2, (i/n) is
>   equivalent to (i>>log2(n)) and (i%n)
>   is equivalent to (i&(n-1)); the
>   compiler will perform these
>   conversions if n is literal.
>
> **Comparison** Throughput of compare, min, max is 8 operations per clock
>   cycle.
>
> **Bitwise Operations** Throughput of any bitwise operation is 8 operations
>   per clock cycle.